# Angular: Check if a form is valid from outside the form (and show the error messages)

Tags: angular, validation, angular6, angular7, mdbootstrap

I have a form but i'm using a button outside the form to submit the data to an API.
The form has error messages for required fields, and hey are shown then a user selects a input but doesn't fill in any data (default HTML5 validation).

Since i'm not actually submitting the form, is there a way to show the same validation messages when the user clicks the button outside the form?

**UPDATE: Added some code to further explain the isse. Also, i forgot to mention that i'm using [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/) as my CSS framework.**

Form HTML (component.html):

```
<form class="custom-form p-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="md-form form-sm">
          <input mdbInputDirective type="text" id="title" [(ngModel)]="dataService.catalog.title" name="title"
            value="{{ dataService.catalog.title }}" required [validateSuccess]="false" placeholder=""
            data-error="This field is mandatory" class="form-control">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="md-form form-sm">
          <input mdbInputDirective type="date" id="date" [ngModel]="dataService.catalog.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
            name="date" (ngModelChange)="date = $event" required [validateSuccess]="false"
            placeholder="" data-error="This field is mandatory" class="form-control">
          <label for="date">Date</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="md-form form-sm">
          <textarea type="text" id="description" [(ngModel)]="dataService.catalog.description" name="description"
            value="{{ dataService.catalog.description }}" required [validateSuccess]="false" placeholder=""
            data-error="This field is mandatory" class="md-textarea form-control" mdbInputDirective rows="3"></textarea>
          <label for="description">Description</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Button HTML (component.html):

```
<button mdbBtn type="button" color="success" class="waves-light" size="sm" mdbWavesEffect (click)="create()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square mr-sm-2 mr-1"></i> Create Catalog
</button>
```

Create Method (component.ts):

```
create() {
    //TODO: call the form's own validation method to show the erros?!   

    if(formValid) {
        this.dataService.create(this.dataService.catalog).subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you show us something you've tried so that we can help ?

Comment: Updated my question with some code samples. The idea is to call the forms own validation methods and not create a custom validation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own functionality. Like store the value of each textbox and on clicking the submit button validate your values.

Comment: Hi! Yes, i know. But what i would like to know if there is a simpler way and just call the form's own validation methods to show the errors without creating a different validation mechanism.

Comment: Then you can use like this 
1)<formname>.ngSubmit.emit()
2)get form status with <formname>.form.valid

<form (ngSubmit)="save()" #custForm="ngForm">
...
</form>

<button class="btn-save button primary"
(click)="custForm.ngSubmit.emit()"
[disabled]="!custForm.form.valid">SAVE</button>

Comment: I've tied that, but it doesn't work because i'm not using a valid ngForm.